# updateOrCreate() update null data if existed in database and only inserted new record

Tags: laravel, eloquent

id_branch is PK, id_item is PK&FK

```
 $id = B;
 $id_selected = A;

$from_category= Category::where('id_branch', $id_selected)->get();
foreach ($from_items as $from_item) {
    $test = Category::updateOrCreate(['id_branch' => $id,'id_item'=>$from_item->id_item], ['remarks' => $from_item->remarks]);
}
```

For example, user will select which branch category record need to be copied to the current branch category. After that will update or insert the record from the branch category selected to current one. Copy branch category A record to branch category B. If exist then update else insert. I able to insert the record but when update the value will be null. Anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Here you are having condition like where('id_branch', 'B')->where('id_item',$from_item->id_item) . is there any record available with same condition?? and which value becomes NULL??

Comment: record is available e.g. branch A consist of 5 records while branch B consist of 2 records, when i am using updateOrCreate(), branch B will be added 3 records. Let's say there is another branch known as C and having the same record with branch B, when i want to update exactly same records with branch C to branch B, when i execute the code, the remarks all will set to null value.

Comment: Branch C - id_product - 7, remarks - abc while Branch B -id_product-7 remarks - cde, when i execute the code the Branch B remarks should be abc same as Branch C but it will set it as null value.

Comment: okay so you want to update id_branch B with the C , Right??

Comment: Can say so, just like if some of the A record exist in B then B will be updated and add the record not existed in B from A. If C have exactly same record with B just with different remarks then only update the remarks in B from C.

Comment: Have you try to get $from_item->remarks?? try to echo it. may be you are not getting value in it , that's why replacing with null in database

Comment: @MeeraTank i tried value all not null, but it set to null when execute the code, i already use dd() to check all data.

Answer (score 1):

`updateOrCreate` method take 2 parameters the first one is the conditions and the second one is the data to update or create.

In your case if the `ID` not exists in the branch, it will create a new row with the given data but you didn't pass the `id_branch` and `id_item` in the second parameter, I guess to fix this issue you should write the code like the following

```
    $test = Category::updateOrCreate(
        [
            'id_branch' => $id,
            'id_item'=>$from_item->id_item
        ],
        [
            'id_branch' => $id,
            'id_item'=>$from_item->id_item,
            'remarks' => $from_item->remarks
        ]
    );
```

Comment: is the `id_branch` and `id_item` are inside the `$fillable` array in `Category` model? and which attributes is saved as null?

Comment: yes, all attribute to be updated will set to default which is null. e.g remarks

Comment: There is other way to make it, but i am curious why updateOrCreate() not working for update the record. So, I try to find out for an answer haha.

Comment: Very strange, it should work fine, did you check if `$from_item->id_item` and `$from_item->remarks` has values?

Comment: Yes, after execute the code then all my value gone. I have no idea why also.